# Accessing members of a Scala object

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have called a Spark RDD's first() methods, and it had returned an object that looks as follows:

```
session: Any = (SessionKey{m_sessionId=91249793986979128, m_publisherId=196, m_sessionStartTimeTimeSlice=1439164800000},Session{m_pageViewsIds=[ViewId [m_viewId=1439166315327]]})
```

How can I access the member variables of this object?

When I run session.getClass, the result is:

```
Class[_] = class scala.Tuple2
```

Yet, when I try to access the members with _1 and _2, I get the following message:

```
error: value _1 is not a member of Any 
session._1
```

When I try to cast it by calling session.asInstanceOf[(SessionKey, Session)]._1, I get:

```
error: not found: type SessionKey    
session.asInstanceOf[(SessionKey, Session)]._1 
error: not found: type Session 
session.asInstanceOf[(SessionKey, Session)]._1
```

Comment: The same way you access the member variables of any object. What's giving you trouble?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Scala. Can you provide an example for reading, say, m_publisherId?

Comment: If you remove the type of `Any` from the variable, it would just be `session._1.m_publisherId`

Comment: If you just remove `: Any` from the declaration, it will infer the correct type. You generally don't need to specify types in Scala.

Comment: I didn't declare this variable. I got it from a Spark RDD.

Answer (score 0):

If you always expect session it to be the same type, then make explicit cast to that type:

```
val sessionWithType = session.asInstanceOf[(SessionKey, Session)]
sessionWithType._1
```

If you are not sure about the type, try matching:

```
val sessionAsOption = session match {
  case s:(SessionKey, Session) => Some(s) 
  case _ => None 
}

sessionAsOption.foreach {
  session => session._1
}
```

It the later example you'll get `Some()` when session matched the expected type and `None` otherwise.